# ASP.NET MVC 5 - "Create" view that can handle any number of elements for an IEnumerable based on clicking an "Add row" button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views

I am writing a recipe manager for my wife in C#/.NET MVC 5. I'm getting to the page for creating a recipe, and I'm a little stumped. A recipe consists of a Name and a list of ingredients.

When I create a view, I have my form:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()){
    //Form elements
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(x => Model.Name)
    //button for adding a new ingredient to the recipe 
    <input type="submit" text="Submit New Recipe!" />
}
```

When the button for adding an ingredient is clicked, it should render a block of html inside the form just above the button itself, that way the user can add any number of ingredients and then submit the recipe back when the form is posted back to the controller.

For this functionality, should I make the button call a controller that sends back a partial view or something? I'm not sure how to accomplish this outside of JavaScript, but I'm wanting to use a .NET MVC solution if I can.

Comment: I always use javascript and something like knockoutjs to do this. Otherwise you'll have to post to the server for every add / edit and it would take ages to enter a recipe with many ingredients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to minimize my reliance on javascript whenever I can, however I agree with @br4d that knockout is your best option here. If you want to avoid it at all cost, it will be more complex, slower and not as user friendly but here is how I would do it.

Enclose the form in a div. Have a place holder div inside the form to hold your ingredients list. Make the "Add new ingredient" call into a controller that will return a partial view with the required fields. In the target attribute indicate the place holder div as the update target and append the response to the html of the place holder div by specifying InsertionMode.InsertAfter.

```
<div id="parentDiv">
    @Html.BeginForm........
        @Ajax.ActionLink("Add New Ingredient","ActionName","ControllerName",routeValues,
                     new AjaxOptions
                    {
                        UpdateTargetId = "ChildDiv",
                        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter
                    }
        <div id=ChildDiv>
        </div>
</div>
```

This code is by no means comprehensive or production ready (I prefer to have a way of handling failed ajax calls and you might want to block off interactions until the call comes back just to mention two of the enhancements). Once again KnockOut would be the preferred way to do this.

Comment: This solved my issue. Thank you very much!

JavaScript is likely the correct way to do this, but I'm also treating this project as a learning experience. I wanted to see how it would be done the "C#/MVC" way rather than the JS way.

Comment: When posting back to the server, since there is an unknown number of elements there, would I need to pass it as a FormCollection and not as a Recipe object?

When can I pass back to the controller as a whole object, rather than a FormCollection or grabbing values from the Request object?